# Understanding npm install command of Tailwind CSS for React

Tags: npm, npm-install, tailwind-css

Consider this npm command from the [Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app#install-tailwind-via-npm):

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

So there is `tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat` and `@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat`. What is the difference between them? What do the double points in `tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat` is the stand-alone TailwindCSS package with compatibility with PostCSS 7.

`tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat` is used to alias `@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat` as `tailwindcss`, meaning `@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat` will now be referenced as `tailwindcss` everywhere in the project.

From [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install):

> `npm install <alias>@npm:<name>`
>
> Install a package under a custom alias. Allows multiple versions of a same-name package side-by-side, more convenient import names for packages with otherwise long ones, and using git forks replacements or forked npm packages as replacements. Aliasing works only on your project and does not rename packages in transitive dependencies. Aliases should follow the naming conventions stated in [`validate-npm-package-name`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate-npm-package-name#naming-rules).